# How do I fix this infinite recursive error?

Tags: python

[LINK for entire problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4fqp.png)
I am trying to write a recursive program that fulfills my prompt of conditions but it seems to fail when I reach the conditions of being divisible by 3 and 4 and the number ending with zeros. I think it's having an infinity problem?? But I am not

[Above conditions that I stated earlier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnflv.png)
The goal of the program is to get to 42 and return True otherwise return False.

```
import math

def bears(n: int) -> bool:
    if n == 42:
        return True

    elif n < 42:
        return False

    else:

        if (n % 2 == 0) and bears(n // 2):
            return True
        if (n % 3 == 0) and bears(n - ((n % 10) * math.floor((n % 100) / 10))):
            return True
        if (n % 4 == 0) and bears(n - ((n % 10) * math.floor((n % 100) / 10))):
            return True
        if (n % 5 == 0) and bears(n - 42):
            return True
    return False

print(bears(250))
print(bears(60))
print(bears(200))
```

Comment: Can you share the link to this problem?

Comment: What is the expected output for each case?

Comment: hiii, i added the link to the problem edits

Comment: you can also get the second digit with `(n//10)%10` or `(n%100)//10` is not really necessary to use the math module

Answer (score 2):

Consider your final example where n=200:

- Since 200 is divisible by 4, your code multiplies the units and tens digits (0*0) and calculates `bears(200-0)` i.e. `bears(200)`

The reason you're getting the infinite recursion is because you call `bears` on the same number (200) over and over again. The recursion never ends.

You need to change your function only slightly to get it to work as needed:

```
def bears(n: int) -> bool:
    if n == 42:
        return True
    elif n < 42:
        return False
    else:
        if (n % 2 == 0) and bears(n//2):
            return True

        if (n % 5 == 0) and bears(n-42):
            return True
        
        if (n % 3 == 0) or (n % 4 == 0):
            #avoid infinite recursion if n doesn't change
            return int(str(n)[-1])*int(str(n)[-2]) != 0 and bears(n-int(str(n)[-1])*int(str(n)[-2]))
        
    return False

>>> bears(250)
True

>>> bears(60)
False

>>> bears(200)
False
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the edits but how come you're returning just True for when it is divisible by 5 and not returning the subtraction of 42

Comment: I editted the inital post with the question now to clear up misunderstandings! Please let me know if there's anything I can change to fix my errors

Comment: in the case of 200, I think it should follow the n%5==0 path and not finish it there

Comment: the condition you introduce if good fine, but 200 is also a multiple of 5, so if fail the fail check you introduce it should go for the multiple 5 route

Comment: your previous check was better by extracting each digit individually, now this will fail to check any of the last 2 digits is zero which result in a zero product of those

Comment: It does. `int(str(n)[-2:]) != 0`. Also I'm not using `elif`. I'm using `if` so it will check ALL conditions and return True whenever it can. i.e. since 200 is a multiple of 5, it WILL go through that path

Comment: no `int(str(n)[-2:]) != 0` fail to check if just one of the digits is zero, like for example n=309, the last two digits are 0 and 9 and their product is 0... and for the second point, you use return, which finish the function right there, so it wouldn't go and to the next if

Comment: @Copperfield - I fixed the first condition with the digits but you're wrong about the `return`. If the condition is `True`, the function returns, otherwise it's moves forward and checks the next condition. I don't understand what you mean "finish the function right right". It goes to the next if ONLY if the previous if is `False`. Which is the intended behaviour.

Comment: now you do the same calculation of the digits twice... and as you should know when a function execute a return, the function end and wouldn't execute any further line of code

Comment: It only returns if it's `True`. If its `True`, the function SHOULD end. Also doing simple math twice is not a big problem.

Comment: I have no problem with that, is with your `return x and b`

Comment: yes, but x is not a condition to do b? is so then if x is false it return false and then it doesn't go and do further checks bellow...

Comment: `x`: product of last two digits is not 0. `b`: `bears(n-x)`. If `x` is False, why do `b`? ie. `x` *is* a condition to do `b`

Comment: because if x is false, it should go to check the condition bellow, namely check if its a multiple of 5, it might success for that branch, but by doing `return x and b` you remove that possibility when x is false, and even if its true too, if b result in false, it still might had succeeded in the branch bellow

Comment: Ah - I finally understood! I moved that condition to the end. Sorry for the confusion lol

Comment: yes, finally... one final thing change bears(n/2) for bears(n//2) so it doesn't give errors with decimal point in str-int conversion

Comment: Done! Thank you for dealing with my stupidity so patiently :P

Comment: no problem, by the way while we were at it I found that 210 is an example of a number that success but failed under the wrong version :p

Comment: Hehe - yeah I bet there were others too. Glad to have had your excellent observations :D